# Heap corruption when freeing 2D dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

I have a simple programa that populates a 2D dynamic char array. Allocation works as usual. My problem relies on freeing arrays. I'm using pure C on VC++ 2008.

This is the piece of code when I allocate and initializes my arrays:

```
char** messsages = (char**)malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
initValorArrayMsgs(messsages, 5);

insertMsgToArray(5, messsages , "Test message.");

void insertMsgToArray(int totalLines, char** msgsArray, const char* msgToInsert)
{
    int line = 0;
    int size= strlen(msgToInsert);

    for(; line < totalLines; line ++)
    {
        if(strlen(msgsArray[line ]) == 0)
        {
            msgsArray[line ] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
            strcpy(msgsArray[line], msgToInsert);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code where I free my arrays

```
void freeArrayMsgs(char** arry, int lines)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < lines; i++)
    {
        if(strlen(arry[i]) == 0){
            break;
        }
        free(arry[i]);
    }
    free(arry);
}
```

When program try to free the first array, it raises a Heap Corruption Exception.

Reading some posts on SO, I'm corretly freeing my array. So, why I'm getting the hep corruption exception?

Comment: `msgsArray[line ] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);` needs to have `(size+1)` instead of `size` to accommodate the null terminator of the string. As a side note, why don't you put your loop initializers right in the `for` loop? For example, `for ( i = 0; i < lines; i++ )` rather than doing the `i = 0;` separately and doing `for ( ; i < lines; i++ )`?

Comment: As well as the above bug, note that you should not cast the result of malloc in C.

Comment: To answer the separate `for` loop question, he is probably not using `-std=c99`.  As he needs to declare the value separately, he might as well set initialize it at the same time.

Comment: @mbratch just for style. And I'll put the addition.

Comment: @MattBryant You got it.

Comment: @Paul For what reason Paul?

Comment: @learner: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Guys your replies were very helpful.

Comment: @PaulR Very interesting resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

- You need to `malloc(size + 1)` to fit the null-terminator.
- There is no need to do `sizeof(char)`- `sizeof` is defined in terms of `char`, so that will always be 1.
- You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` - it is unnecessary and may hide problems.
- As `msgsArray` is not initialized, there is no guarantee `strlen(msgsArray[line]) == 0`.  In fact, it probably won't.  Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` if you want this to be true.
- In general, use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` - it's safer.
- Rather than using `strlen`, it would be a better idea to initialize the `char*`s to `null` and check for `null`. What if the first `msgToInsert` is an empty string, but the rest are real strings? Your code will exit the loop because `strlen(msgs[0]) == 0`, which checking for `null` instead would fix.

Comment: Solved, the heap corruption was occurring because I was missing to fit the null-terminator. Right to the point Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Two things jump out at me:

1. The inner logic of `freeArrayMsgs` seems suspect:  On the first NULL pointer, it stops looping.

   ```
    for ( ;  i < lines;  i++)  
    {  
        if (strlen (arry[i]) == 0)  
            break;  
        free (arry[i]);  
    }
   ```

   Maybe that is okay, but if `lines` is the maximum ever used, it could be important to get them all.  Note that it is perfectly fine to free even NULL pointers—doing so is a no-op.
2. If the code reuses the pointers, it really ought to NULL them out after free().  If the same philosophy implied by the bit of code I see persists throughout the code, you are probably reusing a freed pointer because the stored pointer is not NULL.  That is easily fixed:

   ```
   for ( ;  i < lines;  i++)  
   {  
       free (arry[i]);  
       arry[i] = NULL;  
   }
   ```

Comment: From a quick play it looks like SO doesn't like code formatting within list elements - I deleted your 1. and 2. and code formatting started working.

Comment: @wallyk You just needed to add more indentation.

Comment: @MarkHurd I've inserted break because I want to not delete anything but allocated memory. An ok, I forgot to put null after that. But the problem still there.

Comment: I only corrected the indentation to get the formatting to look right. You may want to @comment to others here.